# Partial Models .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

First of all i shall clarify that i am using Database First Approach using WEB API for a REST service. (Generally Developing The old fashioned way , and using the EF only for some features)

I have a model corresponding to a Database table let's say

```
Model Client
--id
--owns
--address
--VAT number
--Credit card number

Model Session
--id
--clientID (FK)
--date
```

Now there are several times when i want to return only part of a model to the client, and some times combination of model data
{ClientName , Owns , LastSessionDate ) Or several other combinations

Only tactic that comes in mind is creating different models for each response (that comes with duplicate validation declarations etc).
Or when the response is only part of a model(Not a combination) Just nullify the fields i don't want and tell the parser not to render null fields.

Is this the correct way or am i misconceiving something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I have a different model class for each response (or screen/view in a web app).  Sometimes you can re-use these view models, but it's usually more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: That comes to a different problem. Every time you need to retrieve a model the repository gives you the complete model.
I don't think there is a straight way to cast a model to a sub model, or is there?

Comment: @Anestis - True, but generally the model classes you would use for your views would be different than the model classes used by your repository/business layer.  Translating from one to the other is the job of the controller.